# how to resolve Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response <URL>

Tags: javascript, cross-origin-read-blocking

I'm retrieving images URL from my firebase database and then using URLs to dipslay the image in my page

The problem is that i'm getting this error (PS i'm using images URL from wikipedia) 
[image]

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_(magazine) with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response <URL> with MIME type text/html. See <URL> for more details.
```

this is my code :

```
 var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref('titres/');
        databaseRef.once('value' , function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        const list = document.getElementById('favoris');
        [childSnapshot].forEach(item => {
          // add title as an option in the select tag 
            var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
              var row = table.insertRow(0);
              var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
              var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
               let img = document.createElement('IMG');
               cell2.innerHTML=item.val().nom;
               if (item.val().URL_logo != undefined && item.val().URL_logo !="" && item.val()!=undefined &&  item.val().URL_logo !=" " )
               {  console.log(item.val().nom)  
                  console.log(item.val().URL_logo)

                    img.src=item.val().URL_logo ;
                    img.height="42"
                    img.width="100"
                    cell1.appendChild(img)

               }
               else{ cell1.innerHTML=item.val().nom;}
```

Any ideas how to fix this  ?

Comment: The errors mean that the responses are `text/html` instead of an image media type, so the browser blocks them as a security precaution.

Comment: https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/corb-for-developers

Comment: It's generally considered fairly impolite to leech images from somebody else's domain.

Answer (score 4):

When you set the `src` for the image, you need to use a URL which points to an actual image.

You appear to be using URLs to Wikipedia HTML documents instead.

Comment: Or possibly Wikipedia itself is responding to the image leeching with some sort of error.

Comment: @Pointy — The URLs in the screenshot suggest otherwise.

Comment: Well some of them look like they at least *might* be image URLs, but yes others do not. *edit* oh wait that's just the wiki's way of doing things.

Comment: @Pointy — Wikipedia URLs ending in `File:Some_Name.jpg` are HTML documents about image files hosted on Wikipedia.